# How can I use sed to replace a string but retain whitespace?

Tags: sed

I'm trying to use sed to do a fairly simple replace, but I can't figure out how to get it to do what I want. Here's what I want to do:

Given this block:

```
  ./crud/Dailies:
    path: ./crud/Dailies
```

I want to remove the `./*/` part, so the block ends up like this (while preserving whitespace):

```
  Dailies:
    path: Dailies
```

Can someone with more knowledge of sed give me a hand here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replaccing the `./anything/` with noting should not be difficult:

`sed -e 's/\.\/.*\///g' inputfile`

see: https://regex101.com/r/161Xvn/1

Comment: avoid the need for escaping `/` chars by using a different `/regex/repl/` delimiter, i.e. `'s:\./.*/::'` The `g` will have not effect, as the `.*` captures everything to the end of the line. Good luck to all.

Comment: When you might an absolute path (starting with `/`), match on the character after a space or start of line: `sed -r 's:(^| )\./.*/:\1:g' inputfile`